How to overwrite Xcode project disc contents onto .xcodeproj
Suppose I have an Xcode project called Alpha (root dir is /path/to/Alpha). By default, Xcode places the .xcodeproj file at /path/to/Alpha/Alpha.xcodeproj
I might have a few top level folders like /path/to/Alpha/Alpha-iOS, /path/to/Alpha/Alpha-MacOS, /path/to/Alpha/Shared, each with their respective folders and files.
If I make any new files/folders locally on disc inside /path/to/Alpha, and then open Xcode, it is not going to show the new changes.
Can someone provide a programmatic solution in which I could run from shell, which would sync .xcodeproj with the current content stored on disc?
Edit - more background on why I want to do this:
Maybe I am going about this the wrong way - I want to write swift code using another code editor (Cursor) while still having the ability to switch back and use Xcode too. Inside the code editor I will be making new files, folders, etc so I want these changes to reflect in my project's contents when I open Xcode.

Edits to a file that is already part of an Xcode project, when made outside of Xcode, do appear when Xcode displays the file in its editor. The issue therefore boils down to adding to the project some files that you have placed manually in the project folder.
This is typically done just by opening the project in Xcode and adding the files with File > Add Files To (or dragging them into the project navigator). Outside of AppleScript (if it works: see Adding files via Applescript to an Xcode project target), there is no API for programmatically telling Xcode to add files to a project. Any other solution, if one were even possible, would in effect involve physically editing the project file, similar to the way cocoapods modifies the workspace.
New in Xcode 16, there is a feature that will help you to some extent: the "buildable folder". When you say New Folder in Xcode's project navigator, the resulting folder on disk will, by default, add all its contents to the project. Thus you can add new files to this folder outside of Xcode, and Xcode will automatically see them, list them in the project navigator, and include them in its builds.

The main question was about creating new files or folders, you're right regarding edits. I edited my question to remove that part. It definitely is possible to write a script to physically edit the project file to do this - which I tried to do, but wasn't able to do so correctly without getting unexpected effects

Yeah, the thing is that there's a format here that you and I don't know. A file has two references, IIRC, plus there is a unique ID, and I don't think we are capable of supplying that. I can read a project file, well enough at least to deal with merge conflicts (which happen all the time), but I don't believe I'd be able to construct one.

This might be exposing my ignorance about this - but is the only thing we need to change is the .pbxproj text file?

Yes, the XML file that describes the project.

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way - I want to write swift code using another code editor (Cursor) while still having the ability to switch back and use Xcode too. Inside the code editor I will be making new files, folders, etc so I want these changes to reflect in my project's contents when I open Xcode.

Good luck with that. Meanwhile I stand by my answer.

I think, however, that you might be assisted by Xcode 16's new "buildable folder" feature. I'll add that to my answer.
